# Finding the limit when there is the mantissa function involved

Tags: limits, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[image: log is natural logarithm and M(x) is the mantissa function.]

I can't seem to be able to use any known limits and/or variable change for this limit. I just need something to start. (log is natural logarithm and M(x) is the mantissa function.)

Comment: What exactly is the mantissa function ? Is it the number $u$, if $x=u*10^n$ with $1\le u<10$ ?

Comment: Because of $log(e^x)=x$, the intuitive answer is $1$, but I have no idea for a rigorous proof.

Comment: it's this function x-(greatest integer smaller or equal to x) basically 0<=M(x)<1. sorry for the terrible formating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{\log(e^x+1)}{x+1}<\frac{\log(e^x+1)}{x+M(x)}\le
  \frac{\log(e^x+1)}{x}\ .$$
The limit of the LHS and the limit of the RHS are both $1$, so by the pinching theorem (sandwich theorem, squeezing theorem) the limit of the middle term is also $1$.

Comment: Thank you. I figured I had to use the theorem due to the presence of the Mantissa function, but unfortunately I didn't recognize the lhs and the rhs since I haven't studied this case yet(x approaching infinity) . Would you mind saying why those two equal one.